# Double dipping Medicare payments

Tags: united-states, social-security, medicare

I am 78 years old. I collect Social Security, and am on Medicare, and also work part time paying SS and Medicare premiums.

Since Medicare is being deducted from my SS every month, can I get refunded the Medicare premiums I am paying from my part time job?

Answer (score 5):

You are not paying SS and Medicare *premiums* from your part-time wages; you are paying SS and Medicare *taxes* that are imposed on wages, and there is no way of avoiding those taxes. If your income is above a certain level, you are *also* paying monthly Medicare *premiums* that are being deducted from your monthly Social Security benefit check. You cannot get a refund of the Medicare *taxes* that are being withheld from your part-time wages, and you cannot get a refund of your Medicare *premiums* either.